# Mapster - how can I open an alert if every area is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, imagemapster

I want to build a little search picture. So I have defined using mapping some areas in a picture and with Mapster so I am able to select them.

Now I need a possibility to establish an alert if ALL 10 areas are selected.
Something like: Congratulations, you have find everything.

Here is the code:

```
<img id="Map" src="bilderraetsel_gross.jpg" border="0" width="1000" height="750" orgWidth="1000" orgHeight="750" usemap="#Map" alt="Bilderraetsel" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#Map').mapster({
    singleSelect : false,
    highlight : null,
    mapKey : 'data',
    altImage : null,
    isDeselectable : false,
    fill : true,
    fillColor: '0080FF',
    fillOpacity : 0.5,
});
});

</script>


<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area style="cursor:crosshair" data="1" shape="circle" coords="641,378,7" href="#">
    <area style="cursor:crosshair" data="2" shape="circle" coords="918,642,11" href="#">
    <area style="cursor:crosshair" data="3" shape="circle" coords="32,558,8" href="#">
    <area style="cursor:crosshair" data="4" shape="circle" coords="108,584,8" href="#">
    <area style="cursor:crosshair" data="5" shape="circle" coords="195,189,15" href="#">
    <area style="cursor:crosshair" data="6" shape="circle" coords="436,229,6" href="#">
    <area style="cursor:crosshair" data="7" shape="circle" coords="925,346,21" href="#">
    <area style="cursor:crosshair" data="8" shape="circle" coords="949,408,13" href="#">
    <area style="cursor:crosshair" data="9" shape="circle" coords="295,521,14" href="#">
    <area style="cursor:crosshair" data="10" shape="circle" coords="459,309,11" href="#">
</map></p>
```

In the header I am using this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
```

Can anybody help me, please?